# Why doesn't this javascript program successfully access my form values?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsfiddle

Just so you all know, I am new at this. Anyway, I am trying to create a javascript program using jsfiddle that will access the string value in a form and assign it to a variable for further use. This is my html:

```
<body>
    <form name="nameform" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="getInfo(this.form)" />
    </form>
    <h1 id="newname"></h1>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function getInfo(form){
    var name = form.name.value;
    document.getElementById("newname").innerHTML = name;
}
```

However, I always get this error from jsfiddle:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa2f302c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xad2a74c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa2f302c>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0xaae1fec>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

So far I am just trying to get the program to re-display the string you enter in the form underneath the form, just to show that the javascript program is successfully pulling the stringout of the form.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is here any way I could make this program simpler or better?

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/drnY8/

Comment: I think jsfiddle is trolling me...

Comment: Can we see your jsFiddle?

Comment: Change when the script loads from `onLoad` to in `head`.  If I change Zenith's that makes it work or not work.  Having the function created within the `onLoad` functions makes it so it won't be in the global scope and it is inaccessible from the html markup.

Comment: I will look over that. Here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/33qEy/1/

Comment: And it looks like you both are correct. Thank you!

Comment: You changed the code.  Now you have a syntax error.  Regardless, the way you're doing it now should work in the `onLoad` method.

Comment: Oh yeah it looks like my jsfiddle link wasn't the updated version